# Changing color by label names

Tags: spotfire

So I'm trying to change the color by axis names into easier to understand words. I've tried looking at the custom expression however unsure how to modify

Photo:
[image: Axis Screen]

Comment: pls add printscreen or code to precise your question

Comment: @Mankeomorakort 

My bad photo is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZm5TvCXjju75OAI4qSYq7_6w-03lZuj/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Mankeomorakort

Comment: @Mankeomorakort https://imgur.com/gallery/grjV8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Color By legend will show exactly what's contained in the column. so if you don't like what's there, you will need to either change the data in the column (probably a bad idea) or create a new column with the text you want to display.

the easiest way to do that is to **Insert** » **Calculated column...** and use an expression like `If([Column which has True/False], "It worked", "It didn't work")`. you will repeat this for the other column you're using, and then color by those two new calculated columns.